# How to Know if the query is executed successfully in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

In my function, I have an INSERT through a Select..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INSERT_DATA
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T_ITEMS (cd_1,cd_2,cd_3) 
    (SELECT cd_1,cd_2,cd_3 FROM REC_ITEMS);
  COMMIT;
  RETURN 'Return 1 if All is OK else return 0';
END;
```

How do I know that my INSERT has passed and all lines are recorded successfully?

My function should return 1 if everything is OK otherwise return 0.

Comment: you can add exception block to the function in case of any exception you can return 0 otherwise return 1.

Comment: in the exception I can use an ELSE ? for Exemple : `WHEN Others THEN return 0; ELSE return 1;`

Comment: @Mahmoud What do you mean by "all lines are recorded successfully"? In general, if a procedure/function runs without returning an exception (assuming that they don't have a "when others then null" type exception block!) it means it has succeeded. You don't usually need to code a check to determine whether it succeeded or not, since you can raise an exception in cases where an issue occurred.

Comment: It will throw an exception if the insert fails; catching that (e.g. `when others`) is not a good idea. Let the caller handle the actual exception, not a flag that gives no details. But do you also want to know whether anything was actually inserted - since your select could potentially find no rows?

Comment: @Boneist : 
 my table REC_ITEMS does not contain a primary key, then it can contain buddy. while T_ITEM table has a composite key ( CD_1 , CD_2 ) while in case a line is not inserted I have to return a 0 and cancel the insertion .

Comment: @Mahmoud so what you're saying is that you have a unique constraint on your t_item table, and if the constraint is violated, you don't want to continue with the insert? If so, then you'd get a duplicate_val_on_index execption raised if the constraint was violated, and the insert would fail.

Comment: @Boneist 
Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't code this as a function, I'd do it as a procedure, like so:

```
create or replace procedure insert_data
as
begin
  insert into t_items (cd_1, cd_2, cd_3) 
  select cd_1, cd_2, cd_3
  from   rec_items;

  commit;
end;
/
```

If I needed to know how many rows were inserted, I'd add an out parameter like so:

```
create or replace procedure insert_data (p_num_rows_inserted out number)
as
begin
  insert into t_items (cd_1, cd_2, cd_3) 
  select cd_1, cd_2, cd_3
  from   rec_items;

  p_num_rows_inserted := sql%rowcount;

  commit;
end;
/
```

To ensure the transaction is rolled back after the procedure has completed, you could add an exception clause to add a rollback.

Here's an example that demonstrates how it might work:

```
create table t1 (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number, constraint t1_uq unique (col1, col2) using index);

begin
  insert into t1 (col1, col2, col3)
  select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
  select 1, 2, 3 from dual;

  commit;

exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    rollback;
    raise;
end;
/

 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

begin
  insert into t1 (col1, col2, col3)
  select 2, 2, 1 from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 3 from dual;

  commit;

exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    rollback;
    raise;
end;
/

Error at line 10
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA.T1_UQ) violated
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

N.B. I've left the COMMIT/ROLLBACKs in the above example code, but as Alex says in the comments below, typically you would leave the transaction handling for the calling procedure.

---

I would highly recommend you read about exception handling in PL/SQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00701

Comment: for the first time I thought about it. but this is not what I want , it is necessary in case one line do not insert themselves I have to return a 0 and cancel the transaction.

Comment: @Mahmoud Why do you need to return a 0? Just return the error that's raised.

Comment: I'd generally avoid putting commit or rollback in the procedure, and have the caller decide what to do - this may be called as part of a larger transaction and this could cause confusion/corruption. And the caller needs to know there was a problem anyway, since the OP is trying to return a flag at the moment. (This is for the OP's benefit; I realise the question had the commit in the function already, and what you've shown is extending that)

Comment: @AlexPoole Good points re. the commit/rollback; I agree that the calling proc should, in general, keep control over the transaction!